# PHPExcelでページ方向の設定

Tags: php, excel

PHPExcelを使っているのですが、Excelのページタイトル->印刷タイトル->シートでページの方向の設定をしたいのですが、PHP側で設定することは可能なのでしょうか？
Excel2010を使っています。

Answer (score 0):

US版のStackOverflowですが、解答があります。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026645/how-to-use-print-ready-functionality-in-phpexcel-library

`Orientation and Paper Size:` の項を見てください。

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getPageSetup()
    ->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```